# Using pocos to update database

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

Using ASP.NET WebAPI, and EF 5.0.  I've created a data provider that will query the database and then return an object or collection of objects to my client, which happens to be an html5/angularjs app.

The problem is with the updating.  So for example, if I have a Course, which can have many Students.  So I have a `Course` table and a `Student` table with an fk to StudentId.  If I need to edit a student, the EF objects contain everything about a student, including the CourseId, and the Course object itself.

Because of this looping reference, WebAPI pukes when trying to serialize this data, so lazy loading is off- so when I get my Student poco, Course is null.

And then when I update that Student on the client side and then PUT back to my WebAPI, I can't update the DB due to `A referential integrity constraint violation occurred`.

I could make DTO's but before I go that route are there other patterns I should look at to overcome this problem?  Suggestions on other tools or packages to simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WebApi struggles serializing the EF object graph but you should be able to update the entity even without navigation properties are null as soon that your object got a **valid Id**.

Ensure you are attaching it correctly to the context by setting it state to modified:

```
public void Update(DbContext context, User user)
{
    context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Yep I'm doing exactly this :(.  The error occurs setting the state to modified, not actually on SaveChanges().  It's interesting you say I should be able to update even with null navigation properties.  I wonder if there's something else going on...

Comment: The exception indicates there's still some relationship in place. Are the navigation properties of Student decorated with [IgnoreDataMember] ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784507/mvc-4-upshot-entities-cyclic-references

Comment: They weren't but I figured it out... you can set `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;` in Register of WebApiConfig and it ignores null navigation properties... perfect!  Thanks for the point in the right direction